# On element click, get a list of elements that are in the background?

Tags: javascript, onclick

When I click on an element, I'd like to get a list of elements that are in the background and intersect with the clicked element. Is it possible to do this within the click handler?

```js
$('<div id="overlay" />').appendTo('body').on('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    // was the click on top of div#a, div#b or both? how can I know this?
});
```

```css
body{
    position: relative;
}

div{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

#overlay{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
    test
    <div id="b">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to manually loop through all elements in the DOM and compare the bounding box with the clicked mouse position. The event object itself is not aware of any CSS positioning. Something like:

```
$('<div id="overlay" />').appendTo('body').on('click', function(e){
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var elms = $('body *').not(this).filter(function() {
        var b = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        return x > b.left && x < b.left+b.width && y > b.top && y < b.top+b.height;
    });
    console.log(elms);
});
```

You might want to limit the elements to compare with. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o2v6v3gk/

Note that this does not detect whether the elements are "behind" the overlay, z-index speaking.

Comment: Ah I was afraid I'd need to do something like this. Oh well, thanks for the answer :D